# Get name from JSON JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In JS I get a response in string ex.

```
[{"id":"1a869e62-8993-33d0-bd54-f33753044ced","name":"Cubsonx"},{"id":"c534bcba-0096-3668-a34e-a35435e6aafb","name":"Paulina453"}]
```

And from that I want to only have names, ex.

```
[{"name":"Cubsonx"},{"name":"Paulina453"}]
```

and then render every name that is on the list in an discord.js embed fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr.map((el) => el.name);
```

This will return an array with names.

Answer (score 6):

Parse the string to an object:

```
const jsonObj = '[{"id":"1a869e62-8993-33d0-bd54-f33753044ced","name":"Cubsonx"},{"id":"c534bcba-0096-3668-a34e-a35435e6aafb","name":"Paulina453"}]';

const obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
```

then map the array to the desired one:

```
const names = obj.map((item) => ({ name: item.name }));
```

and if you need a string again, then stringify the result:

```
const stringNames = JSON.stringify(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `_.map` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map):

```js
const getNames = function(obj) {
  return {
    name: obj.name
  }
}

const data = [{"id":"1a869e62-8993-33d0-bd54-f33753044ced","name":"Cubsonx"},{"id":"c534bcba-0096-3668-a34e-a35435e6aafb","name":"Paulina453"}]


const newArray = _.map(data, getNames)
console.log(newArray) //result: [{"name":"Cubsonx"},{"name":"Paulina453"}]
```

---

Using plain JS `Array.map` [MDN: Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [{"id":"1a869e62-8993-33d0-bd54-f33753044ced","name":"Cubsonx"},{"id":"c534bcba-0096-3668-a34e-a35435e6aafb","name":"Paulina453"}]

const newArray = data.map((item) => ({ name: item.name }))
console.log(newArray) //result: [{"name":"Cubsonx"},{"name":"Paulina453"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take JSON into obj variable and do

`obj.map((element) => element.name)`

This will return names